# variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)

Tags: objective-c

I have an error in my code that i cannot fix..
here is my code.. it is inside the first if statement where `current_region++` occurs...  please help me, thank you

```
-(void)planetRotation:(UIView *)planet average:(float )time1 perihelion:(float )time2 aphelion:(float )time3 region:(int ) current_region
{
    current_region = 0;

    [planet.layer removeAllAnimations];

    if (current_region == 0 || current_region == 2)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:time1 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
        animations: ^{ CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
                       rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
                       rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * time1 * 1 ];//multiply more to add speed
                       rotationAnimation.duration = time1/4;
                       rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
                       rotationAnimation.repeatCount =  HUGE_VALF;
            [planet.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"orbit"];} completion:^(BOOL finished){current_region++; }];
    }
    else if(current_region == 1)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:time2 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
        animations:^{ CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
                       rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
                        rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * time2 * 1 ];//multiply more to add speed
                        rotationAnimation.duration = 15;
                        rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
                        rotationAnimation.repeatCount =  HUGE_VALF;
            [planet.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"orbit"];} completion:^(BOOL finished){ }];
    }
    else if(current_region == 3)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:time3 delay:0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
            animations:^{ CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
                        rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
                        rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * time3 * 1 ];//multiply more to add speed
                        rotationAnimation.duration = 15;
                        rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
                        rotationAnimation.repeatCount =  HUGE_VALF;
            [planet.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"orbit"];} completion:^(BOOL finished){ }];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare your `current_region` variable you need to modify the declaration like this:

```
__block int current_region = 0;
```

[Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html):

> __block variables live in storage that is shared between the lexical scope of the variable and all blocks and block copies declared or
>   created within the variable’s lexical scope. Thus, the storage will
>   survive the destruction of the stack frame if any copies of the blocks
>   declared within the frame survive beyond the end of the frame (for
>   example, by being enqueued somewhere for later execution). Multiple
>   blocks in a given lexical scope can simultaneously use a shared
>   variable.